# While cycle stucked

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a BattleShip game but I'm struggling adding the ships to the board.

```
void Board::display() const{
    //string filename;

    int upC = 65, lowC = 97; //aqui temos o codigo ascii do a, primeira letra do alfabeto, 65 é o seu uppercase e 97 o seu lowercase
    int icc = 0; //int char coluna

    cout << "  ";

    while (icc < numLines){ //o int char coluna vai aumentando consoante as dimensoes do tabuleiro || e.g Se tivermos um tab 10x10
        cout << (char)lowC << " ";                      //teremos um range de 65-75 [a-j] para as colunas e um range 97 -107 [A-J] para as linhas
        icc++;
        lowC++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    icc = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y< numLines; y++)
    {
        cout << (char)upC << " ";
        for (int x = 0; x < numColumns; x++){
            if(board[y][x] == -1)
                cout << '.' << " ";
            else
                cout << ships[board[y][x]].getSymbol() << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
        upC++;
    }
}
```

I initialized a vector of vectors full of -1's and on my putShip function (see above) I add the ships.

```
int Board::putShip(const Ship &s){
    int size = s.getSize();
    char ori = s.getOri();
    int line = s.getLin();
    int col = s.getCol();
    char symbol = s.getSymbol();

    //vector< vector<char> > tab;

    /*  cout << size << endl;
        cout << ori << endl;
        cout << line << endl;
        cout << col << endl;
        cout << symbol << endl;*/

    while (size > 0){
        if((board[line][col] == -1) && (ori == 'H')){
            board[line][col] = 0;
            col++;
            cout <<  "size " << size << endl;

            return true;
        }
        else if ((board[line][col] == -1) && (ori == 'V')){
            board[line][col] =  symbol;
            line++;
            return true;
        }

        else
            return false;
        size--;
    }

    //cout << line << col << endl;

    /*while (size > 0){
        if(ori == 'H'){
            board[line][col] = symbol;
            col++;
        }
        else{
            board[line][col] = symbol;
            line++;
        }
        size--;

    }*/
    //return true;
}
```

But for some reason it is only printing the first spot of the even though their size is 4. My while loop isnt working and I dont know why.

Here is my Board constructor:

```
Board::Board(const string &filename){
    string nome;
    unsigned int size;
    char simb;
    unsigned int cor;
    char ori;
    PositionChar position;

    string tmp;
    ifstream config;
    config.open(filename.c_str()); //abre o ficheiro config onde estao as informacoes do tabuleiro

    if (config.is_open()) {
        config >> tmp >> numLines >> tmp >> numColumns;
        cout << numLines << endl;
        cout << numColumns << endl;
        board.resize(numColumns, vector<int> (numLines,-1));

        while (!config.eof()) {
            config >> simb >> tmp >> position.lin >> position.col >> tmp >> ori >> tmp >> size >> tmp >> cor;

            if(!config.fail()){
                ships.push_back(Ship(simb, position, ori, size, cor));
            }

            cout << "simbolo: " << simb << endl;
            putShip(Ship(simb,position, ori, size, cor));
        }

        //display();
    } else {
        cout << "Ficheiro de config invalido" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    config.close();
}
```

The couts are debug calls and obviously not relevant to the question. Basically, I got on my txt something like:

```
board: 10 x 10 
P - Aa - H - 4 - 10
```

and then I get the symbol (P), position converted to ints (Aa - position (0,0) , the orientation (Horizontal), the SIZE and the color(irrelevant).

Then I check if some board position x, y is -1, if yes ,it corresponds to water and I fill it with '.' if not. If it has a >= 0 it corresponds to the index of the vector ships which has every ship read from the txt.

My while loop should fill the line with 4 P's since the orientation is horizontal but it doesn't do it and I can't understand why.

Comment: I think this question is more suited to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @user3267581 - no. This question has *"But, somehow it is only printing the first spot of the even though their size is 4. My while cicle isnt working and I dont know how."* - which makes this code "not working" according to Code Review's scope. It would be closed on Code Review.

Comment: Fair point. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the simplest example that still produces the error; then if the cause of the problem is still not obvious, post it.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that in the mass of code that you posted, that you are talking about this loop:

```
while (size > 0){
    if((board[line][col] == -1) && (ori == 'H')){
        board[line][col] = 0;
        col++;
        cout <<  "size " << size << endl;

        return true;
    }
    else if ((board[line][col] == -1) && (ori == 'V')){
        board[line][col] =  symbol;
        line++;
        return true;
    }

    else
        return false;
    size--;
}
```

Note that all paths of that conditional have a return statement. So that while loop will be executed either once or never at all.